# Android Studio Won't Finish Building Project - No Errors shown

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

I press run app (Green Arrow) on the project window:

Displays **"Gradle Build Running"** in the lower part of the screen. 
It is briefly **followed by "scanning files for index."**
Then it suddenly stops and is left where it started.
**No errors or indicators are listed at all.**

*This problem occurs with both the emulator and my phone (which have both worked in the past and work with other projects).

Comment: in the box, left of green arrow, what does it say?

Comment: Mouse over green button - Run 'app'. The thing to immediate left is a little window that opens. It is set to 'app'.

Comment: when you Run -> Edit Configurations -> Android Apps -> app, what values does it show?

Comment: It has a bunch of tabs. General, Debugger, Misc, Profiling. Deploy: default apk; Launch: Default Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Try Building rebuild icon (green hammer near the play button).
If it won't show an error, try pressing the logcat Button at the bottom of the page that must show the error.

PS you can also try the debug mode.

Comment: I've tried the green hammer and debug. Still nothing. The logcat reveals nothing. No indication. No dead processes. No nothing. I've cleaned the project. I've restarted Android Studio. I've rebooted by computer.